# Apollo Client for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, apollo

I have setup an Apollo Server for the GraphQL support in my Express App and I am attempting to set it up with an Apollo Client wrapper for my Cordova App with the AngularJS but can't find any.

If there is any support on the Apollo Client for the AngularJS? I have been recently introduced to the GraphQL and the Apollo Framework and don't know my way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got one for AngularJS. My bad I overlooked this one.

https://github.com/bluecloudy/angular1-apollo

Comment: Your link redirects to a 404.

Comment: @Lodz Updated the link. The previous author removed the project.